# MediatR: iscover at runtime which Request to be triggered and trigger it

Tags: c#, mediatr

I'm trying to make a dynamic mapper to send commands to MediatR based on a request parameter.
I have a parameter called `commandId` that is being sent along with my payload. Based on this parameter, I'd like to discover which Request that I need to trigger and send it through MediatR.

I have a request like the following:

```
// Request
public class Command1GARequest(HeaderAndPayload input) : IRequest<string>
{
    public HeaderAndPayload Input { get; } = input;
}

// Request Handler
public class Command1GAHandler() :
    BaseCommand(CommandNames.Command1GA),
    IRequestHandler<Command1GARequest, string>
{
    public Task<string> Handle(Command1GARequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calling 1GA...");
        return Task.FromResult("result from command");
    }
}
```

I can call this command if I send it straight to MediatR like the following:

```
mediator.Send(new Command1GARequest(...), cancellationToken);
```

Now, based on my payload, I would like to discover dinamically this command and send it properly.
I'm doing a mapper of command name and a type atm:

```
public static class CommandMapper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Type> Commands { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    static CommandMapper()
    {
        Commands[CommandNames.Command1GA] = typeof(Command1GARequest);
    }
}
```

In my discovery method, I'm finding the command by its name and I do have the type with me, but I'm not being able to construct a Request object with arguments and send it over.

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(
  CommandMapper.Commands[decodedMessage.CommandId],
  decodedMessage.HeaderAndPayload
);

var result await mediator.Send(instance, cancellationToken);
```

When I run the code above, I'm getting an issue:

```
Constructor on type '<namespace>.Command1GA.Command1GARequest' not found.
```

Do you have an idea of what is going on?
Or do you have any better alternatives to achieve this goal?

Thanks a lot!